# Porting (postgresql) SQL into django model classes

Tags: django, postgresql

I am porting a database schema (by hand), from (postgresql) SQL to django (1.10) model.

Here is my SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE ref_continent  (
                                    id                  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                                    name                VARCHAR(64)
                            );
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idxu_continent_nm ON ref_continent (name);



CREATE TABLE ref_geographic_region  (
                                     id                  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                                     continent_id        INTEGER REFERENCES ref_continent(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
                                     name                VARCHAR(256)
                                     );
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idxu_geogreg_nm ON ref_geographic_region (name);
```

I am particularly interested in how to create the **UNIQUE INDEX** and how to link the **FK** to the **PKey**, since (AFAIK), django creates the primary key **id** behind the scenes?

Comment: in plsql unique=True automatically means its UNIQUE INDEX and to change PK you  just specify primary_key=True on one of your fields If Django sees you’ve explicitly set Field.primary_key, it won’t add the automatic id column. I can create model file for above if you want

Comment: @Aki003 I'm not sure I understand your comment. Post the model as an answer, that would help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#unique)

> Note that when unique is True, you don’t need to specify db_index,
>   because unique implies the creation of an index.

Well, when you link a model as a foreign key, it links to default FK(that's id by default).

> models.ForeignKey('app_name.ref_continent', )

there is another class class META that is used to fix these things. You don't have to almost ever specify to link FK to PK of other table, this is all done by Django. Have a at [source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/db/models/fields/related/#ForeignKey) 
 models.py

```
  class ref_continent(models.Model):

        # Fields
        name = models.CharField(max_length=64,unique=True)#making unique=True will generate query that will have UNIQUE INDEX both in PLSQL


        def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s' % self.pk



    class ref_geographic_region(models.Model):

        # Fields
        name = models.CharField(max_length=64,unique=True)

        # Relationship Fields
        continent_id = models.ForeignKey('app_name.ref_continent', )


        def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s' % self.pk
```

Comment: Thanks for that. From your code: `models.ForeignKey('app_name.ref_continent', )` where is it linking to the **id** field though? this is not clear. Please clarify.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Updated the answer, inshort django takes care for the searching and linking to PK. Default PK is id, but you can change that.